# How do I set the QT debugger to give more meaningful messages?

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm currently learning the QT framework. I need to know if it's possible to set the debugger to give meaningful messages as opposed to what it gives me right now, which is the failed step in the build process (usually the '.o' file) I need to know if it's possible to set it to giving meaningful message like Visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger is not involved in the build process. Those errors messages come either from the compiler or the linker, or the moc compiler.

You can try `qmake -d` to make it extra verbose. That might help you understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: thanks.. I know the debugger isn't involved in the process it's just I'd like to get more out of it than it just spitting that failure of the Make process like say for instance the file where that caused the compilation error.